# Proceso de sincronización con Flutter y SQfLite mediante Api Rest C#

Tags: c#, flutter, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, sqflite

soy nuevo en esto de programación con Flutter y SQLLite, quisiera saber cuál sería la mejor forma de realizar un proceso de sincronización de un Api Rest C#, de una gran cantidad de registros, los cuales serán almacenados en la base de datos local del dispositivo móvil con SQLLite, entiendo que tengo las siguientes opciones y no se cual seria la mejor en temas de seguridad, como de rendimiento de la aplicación,

1. Crear un proceso de sincronización en el BackEnd, que me envié todos los datos necesarios, mediante una petición http al servicio Rest C# e ir almacenado en el dispositivo móvil, no me lo recomiendan por temas, tiempo de sincronización que será muy largo.
2. Generar un listado con las sentencias DML, tales como INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, me indican que será más rápido, la inserción de los datos.
3. Crear un archivo SQLLite, del lado del BackEnd y luego copiar ese archivo SQLLite al dispositivo móvil y atachar la base de datos y hacer un insert or replace.
   Quisiera escuchar sus opiniones ya que soy nuevo en esto de crear aplicaciones, para dispositivos móviles y las recomendaciones, que me recomiendan tanto a nivel de rendimiento, como a nivel de seguridad y escalabilidad,
   Agradecería sus comentarios,

Comment: La sincronización sería bidireccional??

Comment: Entiendo que si porque en caso que se le quiera o se desee enviar los datos de una tabla en especifico debería ser así